# Fire Event once per session - Implementation problems

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics, conversion-tracking

Please I'm looking to set up tags on GTM to **fire only once per GA session**. However, I'm unable to do so.The tags end up firing multiple times in the same sessions.

Would appreciate it if anyone can help.

Many Thanks :)

Comment: Sessions are managed server-side in GA3, in GA4 you can determine the current session via the set cookies. Alternatively, you can create a segment in GA3 to only include sessions in which your event has fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let's assume you have two conditions, that have to be checked for a session to be high quality.
What I would do ist create a session cookie (see https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/cookies-with-google-tag-manager/), that contains a stringyfied object:

```
{
"condition 1": "true", //has been fullfilled
"condition 2": "false",//has yet to be fullfilled
"event_fired": "false"//flag to fire event only once per session
}
```

Whenever a user acts in a way, that should update this cookie, you fire a custom HTML Tag, that reads & updates it. If all conditions are met and the key "event_fired" equals "false", the tag also executes a dataLayer.push event, that you can use to trigger an event, that marks the session as high quality. In addtion to the dataLayer.push event, the HTML Tag then sets "event_fired" as "true" - thus preventing the dataLayer.push event to be executed again.

Answer (score 2):

Just set a session cookie as a flag after the event has fired the first time.
The events trigger should be configured to fire only, when the cookie does not exist.
You could use sessions storage as well, but it doesn't work for new browser tabs.

Comment: Thanks, @Ramon.  What I'm looking to achieve here is to use a set of rules to define which sessions are Quality sessions. I currently have a quality session segment where all the rules are correctly defined. But I also wish to use these Quality sessions as Conversion goals.
I’ve tried grouping all the triggers for these rules under a GTM Tag; however, upon testing these, the figures still do not align with what I have from the Quality session segment.
Would appreciate it if you could share any resources on setting session cookies with GTM. Thanks :)